# Problems forcing a ScrollView to move to the top

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that I want to move programatically to the top.

I do the following:

scrollll5.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
   scrollll5.postInvalidate();

and it works, but only if the ScrollView is NOT at the bottom already...

has anybody found a similar problem (and its solution)?

Comment: Won't the `scrollTo(0,0)` solve your problem? It won't change the `ScrollView`'s position as smoothly as the way you've shown, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTo(0,0)` or `smoothScrollTo(0,0)` should work.